# Optimize left join with several joins by OR?

Tags: mysql, optimization, left-join

This is my query (edited)

```
SELECT
  en.name AS name,
  en.entity_id,
  COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders_qty,
  ROUND(SUM(o.total)) AS orders_sum,
  ROUND((SUM(o.total) / COUNT(o.order_id))) AS average_purchase,
  MIN(o.date_added) AS first_purchase,
  MAX(o.date_added) AS last_purchase,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oc_order WHERE order_status_id <> 0 AND customer_id = c.customer_id AND date_added <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) as periodicity
FROM oc_xile_entity en
  LEFT JOIN oc_xile_customer_to_entity c2en ON (c2en.entity_id = en.entity_id)
  LEFT JOIN oc_customer c ON (c2en.customer_id = c.customer_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_order o FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`unreg_customer_id`) ON ((o.customer_id = c2en.customer_id OR o.unreg_customer_id = c2en.customer_id) AND order_status_id <> 0)
  WHERE en.entity_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY en.entity_id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0,700
```

...and the relevant parts of the tables...

```
CREATE TABLE oc_order 
( order_id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
, customer_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
, unreg_customer_id (unreg_customer_id)
, unreg_customer_id int(11) NOT NULL
, order_status_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
, INDEX (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE oc_customer 
(customer_id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE oc_xile_customer_to_entity 
(entity_id int(11) NOT NULL
,customer_id int(11) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (entity_id,customer_id)
,INDEX entity_id
);
```

When i do query its take more than 15sec in table order 35506 rows

The most heavy query its

```
LEFT JOIN oc_order o ON ((o.customer_id = c2en.customer_id OR o.unreg_customer_id = c2en.customer_id) AND order_status_id  0)
```

The best way to optimize it to add `FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (unreg_customer_id)` like this `LEFT JOIN oc_order o FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (unreg_customer_id) ON ((o.customer_id = c2en.customer_id OR o.unreg_customer_id = c2en.customer_id) AND order_status_id <> 0)`
its increase speed and query time has become 3secs. But i think it can optimize much better. Can anybody help me?
Explain of query
[image: explain]

Comment: Left joins and group by I am use right, without this my query return wrong results. You say that no sense in optimizing, why?

Comment: So its possible to optimized the ```LEFT JOIN oc_order o FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (unreg_customer_id) ON ((o.customer_id = c2en.customer_id OR o.unreg_customer_id = c2en.customer_id) AND order_status_id <> 0)``` this only? change by another query like union? any ideas?

Comment: We clearly share very different concepts of right and wrong. I suggest you start over, with a small, sample data set, a desired result, and a brief explanation of how the latter relates to the former. After that, we can talk about optimization. To that end, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sorry for anybody i post not full query = I am edited it

Comment: What happens to performance if you remove the correlated subquery? - And I still don't understand why these are outer joins instead of inner joins

Answer (score 0):

Duh?  The query does nothing with the `LEFT JOINs`.  However, the Optimizer is probably too dumb to throw them away and get the equivalent query:

```
SELECT  en.name AS name , en.entity_id
    FROM  oc_xile_entity en
    WHERE  en.entity_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY  en.entity_id
    ORDER BY  name ASC
    LIMIT  0 , 700
```

Then it is likely to be 'improper' in that you are selecting `name` but not grouping by it.  If there are several `names` associated with one `entity_id`, then *which* `name` should be displayed?

Please describe what you are trying to achieve, plus provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE oc_xile_entity`.